# Command ">" is identing twice

Tags: vim

When I use `>` command to indent something, it is indenting twice, i mean:

```
This is a code
This is too
Me either
```

Applying `>` command:

```
This is a code
        This is too
Me either
```

Expected result:

```
This is a code
    This is too
Me either
```

Yes, my `ts=4`.

Comment: yup, dont you wanna answer down there? I wanna check as right yay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set:

```
set shiftwidth=4
```